# Shows Logout Button after confirm login and goes to activity while login using Facebook Login Integration Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am using Facebook login integration for my android application. I can login and go to the next activity but the problem is that , after login using facebook login button  it shows facebook logout button for a while after clicking yes for confirm page and goes to my activity. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Set Facebook Login button setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

Facebook login button if you success login.. it will change the wording from "Log In Facebook" to "Logout".. if you dont want to see that, just setVisibility GONE or Intent to desired activity. If you using intent, set the flag like below

```
Intent next = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
next.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(next);
```

Below is the example of facebook loginbutton

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), (object, response) -> {
                    // hide this facebook login button
                    // Intent to your desired activity

                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,birthday,gender,first_name,last_name");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Message.LOGINCANCEL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Message.LOGINFAILED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If you want to change the "Logout" facebook button to "Log in Facebook" use below code.. just create BUtton and do onClick() to trigger below code

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null){
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }
```